Incorrectly registered broadcast receiver
I am getting an issue while pushing my app to the Google Play Console.
Incorrectly registered broadcast receiver
Apps targeting Android 13 or later must specify the export behavior when calling registerReceiver(). Having unspecified export behavior may cause your app to crash.
Your app targets Android 13 or later and registers non-system broadcast receivers without specifying their export behavior in the following places:
Update your app so it specifies the export behavior for registered broadcast receivers.
I have the regiserReceiver is like the below code.
  ContextCompat.registerReceiver(this, mMessageReceiver, filter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);

<receiver
            android:name=".widget.WidgetProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" /></intent-filter><meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/">
        </receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name=".utilities.customtabs.ShareBroadcastReceiver" /> 


Remember that even if your own code is registering BroadcastReceivers correctly, keep in mind that your project's dependencies might be outdated and registering receivers the wrong way.

I have different build variants in the same code base. other apps are working. This alone making the issue

You have to set the export in the Manifest file to true or false
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="APP_SPECIFIC_BROADCAST" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Also when you try to send a broadcast like this:
val intent = Intent().apply {
    action = "YOUR_ACTION_HERE"
    `package` = "YOUR_ACTIVITY_PACKAGE_NAME"
}
sendBroadcast(intent)

And here is the last step while registering the broadcast:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
   getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
  } else {
   getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
  }


registerReceiver must need a flag at the end. Receiver is missing RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag for unprotected broadcasts registered for EVENTS More... (⌘F1) Inspection info:In Android U, all receivers registering for non-system broadcasts are required to include a flag indicating the receiver's exported state

Can you please provide the code snippet for your situation?

updated in the question itself
